# filter particular element from a list in a dict

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like filter a list as the value from one key of dictionary and convert element in list into int. The elements in list may have *''* or *...*
I have some stupid code as following but how can have more pythonic way or one line to do it?

```
def fil(d:dict):
    rtn = dict()
    for k, v in d.items():
        rtn[k] = [int(x) for x in v if x and x != '...']
    return rtn

d = dict( name=['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], state=['21', '', '22', '...', '23'], number=['11', '...', '12', '13'])
print(fil(d))
```

Comment: What you have is fine.  The only thing worth changing is:  either operate in place and don't return any value, or create a copy and return it.  Don't modify in place *and* return the object.

Comment: like what I have updated? created a empty dict and return it?

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly reduce it to one line by using a dictionary comprehension as well as the list comprehension:

```
{k:[int(x) for x in v if x and x != '...'] for k,v in d.items()}
```

An alternative would be to define just the list transformation as a function and then write `{k:fil(v) for k,v in d.items()}` which illustrates the separable dictionary and list handling (and doesn't feel like so much of a mouthful).

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a "pythonic" way, I'd say what you have is fine.

If you are looking for a one-liner, then perhaps:

```
>>> def fil(d):
        return {k: [int(x) for x in v if x and x != '...'] for k, v in d.items()}

>>> d = dict( name=['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], state=['21', '', '22', '...', '23'], number=['11', '...', '12', '13'])
>>> print (fil(d))
{'name': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'state': [21, 22, 23], 'number': [11, 12, 13]}
>>>
```

What this comes down to is what you are defining as "pythonic". Comprehensions are generally considered fairly "pythonic", and this is a list comprehension within a dictionary comprehnsion!

That said, if the function meets PEP standards, is syntactically correct and cant easily be reviewed by another programmer as to ascertain its purpose, why change it?

On another note, unless you are pressed to use the `typing` syntax in your params, remove it.